# Python If Value of pixel in an image is then print

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a small image that I would like to find all RGB values that are the same and then compare that against my variable and if the match print match or similar.

Below is a little snippet that I have put together from other sources.

I am able to print that I found the colour but it will print a line for every time that value is found in the image.

Is there a better way to search an image and match that to a single RGB value? Then if found do a thing.

```
import cv2

path = '3.png'

blue = int(224)
green = int(96)
red = int(32)
img = cv2.imread(path)
x,y,z = img.shape

for i in range(x):
  for j in range(y):
    if img[i,j,0]==blue & img[i,j,1]==green & img[i,j,1]==red:
      print("Found colour at ",i,j)
```

Comment: If you're just trying to print the first value, you should `break` or `return` so that the loop stops running.

Answer (score 2):

General Python advice: **do not** say `blue = int(224)`. Just say `blue = 224`

Your program expects to find those exact values. In any kind of photo, nothing is exact. You need to find **ranges** of values.

`cv.imread` returns data in BGR order. Be aware of that if you access individual values in the numpy array.

Use this:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("3.png")

lower_bound = (224-20, 96-20, 32-20) # BGR
upper_bound = (224+20, 96+20, 32+20) # BGR
mask = cv.inRange(img, lower_bound, upper_bound)
count = cv.countNonZero(mask)
print(f"picture contains {count} pixels of that color")
```

And if you need to know *where* pixels of that color are, please explain what you need that for. A *list* of those points is generally useless. There are more useful ways to get these locations but they depend on why you need this information, what for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you with small touching :)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

r = int(255)
g = int(255)
b = int(255)

img = 255*np.ones((5,5,3), np.uint8)

[rows, cols] = img.shape[:2]
print(img.shape[:2])
print(img.shape)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if img[i, j][0] == r and img[i, j][1] == g and img[i, j][2] == b:
            print(img[i, j])
            print(i, j)
```